# What part of speech is this 'as'?

Tags: parts-of-speech

This is from [a news article](https://apnews.com/article/airbus-india-airplane-order-paris-air-show-55300e40a9510452188c30cfc534ff4b) :

> Airbus likes to unveil major jet orders at the air show held every
> other year in its home country. Airbus is one of France’s — and
> Europe’s — biggest companies, and its performance at the Paris air
> show is seen **as** important to its public image in France.

It seems that 'as' is a preposition, but I wonder whether it can take an adjective ('important' here) as its object, rather than a noun.

Comment: Merriam-Webster [says](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as) it's a conjunction, but I'm sure it's debatable how you want to describe it. It's certainly grammatical here.

Comment: @StuartF Thank you very much. You mean "as (it is) important...". Right?

Comment: It's a preposition.

Comment: @BillJ Thank you very much.

Comment: @BillJ Do prepositions not require a noun complement?

Comment: Grammatically, the adjective phrase "important to its image in France" is predicated of "its performance at the Paris air show". But the adjective phrase is complement of the preposition "as", not of the verb "seen", so it's called an 'oblique predicative  complement'.

Comment: The sentence is grammatically correct.  The words "is seen as" mean "is considered" or "is thought to be" - it's an idiom, not literal.

Comment: check this out: [see as - sense 3.](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/see+as)

Comment: @gotube Not always: Compare "I regard her as indispensable", where "indispensable" is an AdjP, not an NP, but it's just as much a complement of "as", as the NP "a friend" is in "I regard her as a friend". Such complements are regarded as 'predicative obliques'.

Comment: @BillJ Thanks! Here's more reading for anyone else interested: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_prepositions#Other_complements_of_prepositions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... *its performance at the Paris air show is seen as important to its*
> *public image in France.*

Grammatically, the adjective phrase "important to its public image in France" is predicated of "its performance at the Paris air show".

The adjective phrase is complement of the preposition "as", not of the verb "seen", and hence is called an 'oblique predicative complement'.

Comment: In that analysis, what do you call "is seen" ?

Comment: @GratefulDisciple "is seen" is not a constituent and hence has no name. "Is" is predicator in the matrix clause verb phrase "is seen as important to its public image", and "seen" is predicator in the subordinate clause verb phrase "seen as important to its public image".

Comment: Thanks.  Do you have a recommendation for an advanced English grammar book for naming constructs like "oblique predicative complement" but not as exhaustive as the venerable [The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cambridge_Grammar_of_the_English_Language) ?

Comment: You need CGEL for a full discussion of such complements. Generally, I can recommend [link](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Students-Introduction-English-Grammar/dp/0521612888) by the same authors. Look around for the best price, perhaps second-hand.

Comment: I will.  Thanks for the recommendation!

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the sentence to active form will help:

> Airbus is one of France’s — and Europe’s — biggest companies, and [people] see its performance at the Paris air show as important to its public image in France.

- There is an implied (missing) subject: people / audience
- The verb is "see"
- The object is "its performance", described further by a location clause "at the Paris air show"

Now it's easier to see that "as important to its public image in France" is a further **elaboration of the verb "see"**, an answer to the implied question "What do people see?"

What part of speech is the "as" in that sentence? Since it modifies a verb, I think it is **a preposition introducing an adverbial phrase**.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: @elise I think BillJ's answer is the correct one, I recommend you accept his answer instead.